# ASP.NET : populate many label from one SQL command

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

It is possible to populate many labels from one `SqlCommand` instead of writing many `SqlCommand`?

For example

```
select name from users where ID=1
select name from users where ID=2
select name from users where ID=3
select name from users where ID=4

Label1.Text = //here should be ID 1
Label2.Text = //here should be ID 2
Label1.Text = //here should be ID 3
Label2.Text = //here should be ID 4
```

So I ask - is it possible using just one `SqlCommand`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I ask how/or if is possible to using one sql command to populate multiple Labels with different ID like where ID=1-for Label1 Text , where ID=2 for label2.text

Comment: Are you using ADO.NET, LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: No im using normal web form

Comment: Write a function that takes in an ID and returns the name? The function would use a parameterized query to get the name? Seems like if you just *try* something you might be able to figure this out.

Comment: "No I'm using web form" does not make sense in reply to `Are you using ADO.NET, LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework?` Web Forms is a web application framework. ADO.NET, Linq to SQL, and Entity Framework are all database application frameworks/libraries. How you implement your code depends on which database technology you're using. Do you have any other database related code in your application yet?

Comment: here is code
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=localhost; database=Site; trusted_connection=true;");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select name from users where ID=1", con);
            
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Label1.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
            }

            dr.Close();
            con.Close();

Comment: Then you are using ADO.NET, which is when you use SqlConnection directly (or some other provider that implements `System.Data.Common.DbConnection`.

Comment: I did not have any knowledge about it im sorry.
I was just hope to use one command to populate 10 labels with different ID

Comment: If you want multiple records to come back from the database, consider rewriting your sql where clause or eliminating it altogether.  No need for multiple select statements.  For instance, "Select name from users" or "Select name from users where ID between @x and @y".  Then use a repeater or some sort of loop to fill your labels dynamically in your UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your confirmation that you use ADO.NET, here is what you are looking for-

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=localhost; database=Site; trusted_connection=true;"); 
con.Open(); 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select id, name from users where ID Between 1 and 4", con); 
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
while (dr.Read()) 
{
   if(dr["id"].ToString() == "1")
     Label1.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
   else if(dr["id"].ToString() == "2")
     Label2.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
   else if(dr["id"].ToString() == "3")
     Label3.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
   else if(dr["id"].ToString() == "4")
     Label4.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
} 
dr.Close(); 
con.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This is what i need.